# fail to put Base64 String in json

Tags: android, json, base64

My Base64 String is converted from photo. I try to put them in my json object but it will result in part of Base64 String being cutting and even the other json object could disappear. When I replace the original one with short Base64 String, the json format will be ok. How could I fixed it?

```
  public void TakePhotoOnClick(View view) {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    file = Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    file = new File(file, "picture.jpg");
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
    if (isIntentAvailable(this, cameraIntent)) {
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PICTURE);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msg_NoCameraAppsFound,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

private boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.w(" MainActivity","onActivityResult");
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());
        ivDriverPhoto.setImageBitmap(picture);

        ByteArrayOutputStream out1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, out1);
        image = out1.toByteArray();
        driver_photo = Base64.encodeToString(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.w(" MainActivity","image"+ driver_photo );

    }

}
```

**The photo Base64 String is like the following string:**
image/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDABALDA4MChAODQ4SERATGCgaGBYWGDEjJR0oOjM9...
(it's too long to show it completely.)

**And the short test Base64 Sting is as below:**
image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAQAAAC1+jfqAAAAAnNCSVQICFXsRgQAAAAJcEhZcwAAAHoAAAB6AZUMqX8AAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHd3dy5pbmtzY2FwZS5vcmeb7jwaAAAA4ElEQVQoz6XRzyvDcRgH8JdJObmsJMUf4KIotaJEUYrLNPnxTY4r3Ocw32K+HwpxmZ1cNH/C/rzHYVvNZQ56X1/P09P7EcbHn0AmH5OMYux8QQqmXSk8K8yasCWX2zMZpD44txSCDccOVZVsaqiPgm+v2roqntxpq/n0oTQEy05CcGnem1YIrnSUByDIzVlwY1FNS+bIix1rww3beh4kPR119y6cSs40JJIDTeuaCquSjtsQXHu32wePSkHZTNA0paFqX2FCkij6VwyKyUOwohKCpCDTHan261fRXZl/f/MHNSqo8Xq9umsAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

Comment: So your problem is when you try to put `driver_photo` in a JSON object? In your code there is nothing related to json... Also it's weird that both base64 strings have `image/` in the beginning... They are generated by Base64.encode ?

Comment: Yes, the Photo Base64 String is from Log(Log.w(" MainActivity","image"+ driver_photo )).

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by using BitmapFactory to reduce the picture size and the Base64 string would be short enough to put in json.